# Javascript static variables and using in different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin in my layout page header:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/jsCommon.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/Layout.js")"></script>
```

and my layout.js:

```
    (function ($) {
    var Layout = function (node, options) {
        this.node = node;
        this.options = $.extend({
            url: ""
        }, options);
        $(this.node).find('.HButton').bind('click', $.proxy(this.HButtonClicked, this));
    };

    Layout.prototype = {
        constructor: Layout,
        _loadBackground: function () {
            debugger;
            //load second now 'Common.currentTarget' have been lost
            $(Common.currentTarget).removeClass();
            $(Common.currentTarget).addClass(".HButton_Selected");
        },

        HButtonClicked: function (e) {
            debugger;
            //load first
            Common.currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
        }
    }

    $.fn.Layout = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).data('Layout', new Layout(this, options));
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
```

in the other side I have a share repository javascript object like this :

```
function common() { 

}

common.currentTarget = null;

var Common = new common();
```

then in the other page I've triggered an event like following :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var layout = $("#layout").data("Layout");
    $(layout).trigger("_loadBackground")
  });
</script>
```

when the HButton element click happened at the first I'm writing the object inside the "Common.currentTarget" and it saved successfully when I've watched variable but when another page loads completely and then trigger the event "_loadBackground" the value of "Common.currentTarget" have been lost, my question is how I can define a static variable like this to be permanent in whole of my pages?

Comment: You want a variable to stay populated after changing page? If so you'll have to put it into some kind of storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a cookie from javascript to store the data, and then access the cookie from another page. Cookies can persist just during the browser session, or you can give them an expiration. For HTML5, there is [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: Are there any side effects if I use localstorage I think it is solution (but only for HTML5)?

Comment: @kamiar3001 It is widely used and supported. See http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/ for the compatibility matrix. Some browsers may be configured to ask the user if it's ok for the page to store some local data. Session storage is probably sufficient for your case, rather than persistent local storage.

Comment: Session storage store only text but how about Jquery object??

Comment: @kamiar3001 You will have to convert it to a json string. jquery probably has support or plug-ins to support it -- google it.

Comment: JSON.stringify(e.currentTarget) => it gets me like this : "{\"jQuery19106981751315333444\":15}"

Comment: There are some jquery plugins to directly support local storage described here: http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/localstorage/

Comment: I think I need implementation or sample using localstorage which store object and then get and change it.

Answer (score 0):

All JavaScript data is unloaded when the page is changed or refreshed.  There is no way around this in JavaScript itself.  You will have to send data to the server instead.  Probably the easiest way to do this is to store your data in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="storable" />
....
document.getElementById("storable").value = // whatever value you want to store
```

Then on the server side you can transfer that data to the new page.

If you are redirecting client side, use a query parameter instead.

Comment: But how about OOP javascript like define a static variable in namespace? is that possible I like to implement this as kind of the design pattern.

Comment: @kamiar3001 No, if you're interested head on over to Mozilla's Firefox source code and you can see that the whole DOM is unloaded every time the page changes.  There's just no way to do it.  What you could do is host everything on one page, although that's a serious thing to do and I don't recommend it.  You'd still lose your state on a refresh anyway.